# Rails reload! resets class variables, need to rerun some initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

Suppose I need to parse some configuration to instanciate some Service Singletons (that could be used with or without Rails).

A sample code example:

```
#services/my_service.rb
module MyService
    @config = nil

    def self.load_config(config)
      @config = config
    end
```

When using with Rail (or Capistrano, SInatra, etc.) I would use an initializer to boot up the service

```
#initializers/svc.rb
MyService.load_config(Rails.application.secrets.my_service.credentials)
```

But when used specifically with Rails, on every rails console `restart!`, this @config variable is cleared which is a problem...

Are there

- `after-reload!` hooks that I could use to re-run the initializer ?
- other types of variables that would be preserved during a `restart!`
  that I could use here ?

Comment: This is an old question but since there are new readers : after-restart, etc. hooks are available inside ActiveSupport::Reloader from Rails 5. See the doc http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/ActiveSupport/Reloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that people are still reading this, here is implementation I ended up with

```rb
# config/initializers/0_service_activation.rb
# Activation done at the end of file

module ServiceActivation
  def self.with_reload
    ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare do
      yield
    end
  end

  module Slack
    def self.service
      ::SlackConnector
    end

    def self.should_be_activated?
      Utility.production? ||
      Utility.staging? ||
      (
        Utility.development? &&
        ENV['ENABLE_SLACK'] == 'true'
      )
    end

    def self.activate
      slack = service
      slack.webhook = Rails.application.secrets.slack&.dig(:slack_webhooks)
      Rails.application.secrets&.dig(:slack, :intercept_channel).try do |channel|
        slack.intercept_channel = channel if channel.present?
      end
      slack.activate
      slack
    end
  end

[
  ServiceActivation::Intercom,
  ServiceActivation::Slack,
  ServiceActivation::Google
] .each do |activator|
  ServiceActivation.with_reload do
    activator.activate if activator.should_be_activated?
    activator.service.status_report
  end
end
```

I am not showing my connector class `SlackConnector`, but basically you can probably guess the interface from the way it is called. You need to set the webhook url, and do other stuff. The implementation is decoupled, so it's possible to use the same SlackConnector in Rails and in Capistrano for deployment, so it's basically in the `lib/` folder

Answer (score 0):

You could define config method as:

`def config
  @config ||= Rails.application.secrets.my_service.credentials
end`

And call this method instead of `@config`, so when the config variable is unset, it will be set again, otherwise it will return the value.

Comment: The problem here is that you couple the implementation with the Rails framework. I had separated into an initializer (that just provides the credentials) and the service itself, because the service could be used outside Rails, and it was the job of the initializer to pass in Rails secrets. I'll add this to my question and a Ruby tag as well

Comment: That's true. What about using a yaml file instead of the secrets one? You will avoid coupling the logic between the framework and the keys. (I think that your problem is not a very common problem haha)